# Why is the following true? functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

$$x , x_0 \in [a,b]$$ $x_0$-fixed
$f \in D(a,b)$- differentiable   on [a,b]
$$\triangle (x)=f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

$$\triangle '(x)=f'(x)-f'(x_0)$$

Comment: In $\Delta$, the derivative of $f$ is of course $f'$; the coefficient of $x$ inside the parenthesis is the $-f'(x_0)$ outside of the parenthesis. (This isn't very coherent of me - but Is that clear? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just an application of the basic properties of the differential, so that means:

$\triangle (x)=f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)=f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x+f'(x_0)x_0$

while $x_0$ is fixed and therefore $f(x_0)$ and $f'(x_0)$ are constants.
If we now differentiate $\triangle (x)$ we differentiate the above sum and are allowed to differentiate each term on its own (differentiation is linear), we then get

$\triangle (x)'=(f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x+f'(x_0)x_0)'=f(x)'-f(x_0)'$

since the differentiation of constants is equal to $0$.

bests

Comment: thanks, I cant believe I didn;t see that

Comment: a very common feeling :)